# Ubuntu freezes after login

Tags: 17.10

I just updated my Ubuntu from 16.04 and when I login the screen freezes and the mouse isn't showing. I can't open any software, and I have tried opening my terminal though Alt+Ctrl+F2 and alt+ctrl+t but it doesn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt+F3 or Ctrl+Alt+F4.

Comment: I have, but it didn't work

Comment: updated from 16.04 to what? (17.10)? and how? I'd firstly try alternative logins (unity, gnome, gnome-with-X [not wayland]). if  unsuccessful I'd forget gui & and login [only] via tty/term (ctrl-alt-f2) to see if you can login?   after this my next step would be removing 'quiet spash' from the `linux` line in grub and adding `1` to it so you can see boot up messages  & login to root to refresh memory of what was last done (ie. view `history` or apt logs)  & look for clues (everything mounting ok, space available etc)  ... my first step would be using X11 and not wayland though